# что делает двоеточие вне метода foreach в java?

Tags: java

Когда я ставлю двоеточие после любого слова, которое даже не является какой-то переменной, код принимает это. Допустим, если напишу "gjsdlg:" gjsdlg не будет гореть красным в IDE. Что именно делает это двоеточие?

Comment: Вероятно это метки от goto/break =)

Comment: В языке java есть несколько вариантов использования символа:

1. Часть оператора ::
2. Половина условного оператора ?:
3. В инструкции switch 
4. В assert
5. В расширенном for
6. Обозначает метку безусловного перехода
7. Разделитель. Например разделитель в показе времени.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю как правильно указали вам в комментариях - это оператор метка оператора безусловного [перехода](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1389-operatorih-perekhoda).

> Метка — это любой допустимый идентификатор Java, за которым следует
> двоеточие. После маркировки блока, его метку можно использовать как
> аргумент оператора break. Это приведет к тому, что выполнение будет
> продолжено с конца помеченного блока. Например, следующая программа
> содержит три вложенных блока, причем каждый имеет свою собственную
> метку. Оператор break осуществляет переход вперед, за конец блока,
> маркированного меткой second, пропуская два оператора println().

```
// Использование break как цивилизованной формы goto.

public class Break {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean t = true;
    first:
    {
      second:
      {
        third:
        {
          System.out.println("Перед оператором break.");
          if (t) {
            break second; 
// выход из блока second

          }
          System.out.println("Данный оператор никогда не выполнится");
        }
        System.out.println("Данный оператор никогда не выполнится ");
      }
      System.out.println("Данный оператор размещен после блока second.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял. То есть, так как t == true, все, что будет в блоке first и second НЕ отработает, отработает только блок third? *** Или наоборот, отработают только first и second а до third не дойдет?

Comment: Проверить не сложно. Посмотрите запустите и поймёте что и как